# pip installing in usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages instead of virtualenv on ubuntu server

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm having a problem when installing packages on my virtualenv.It all started when I upgraded my pip to the latest version. I tried to revert my pip version to where I find it stable. When I try to install, for example, django-tables2, it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: django-tables2 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Django>=1.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from django-tables2) (2.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from Django>=1.11->django-tables2) (2019.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from Django>=1.11->django-tables2) (0.3.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

But when I check my folder in my virtualenv, it doesn't show there. I tried some commands like `which pip` and `which pip3` and it says this:

```
(unidaenv) root@UnidaWebApplication:/home/unidaweb/unidaproject# which pip
/home/unidaweb/unidaproject/unidaenv/bin/pip
(unidaenv) root@UnidaWebApplication:/home/unidaweb/unidaproject# which pip3
/home/unidaweb/unidaproject/unidaenv/bin/pip3
(unidaenv) root@UnidaWebApplication:/home/unidaweb/unidaproject#
```

I also tried `pip list` but I can't find the package that I installed to my virtualenv.

I'm getting a `bad gateway error` when I try to add it on my `settings.py`, I don't really know how to fix this but when I'm in the version of pip that I know was stable running my project, I don't get this error and I can install any package that I needed to my project. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm stuck on this for about a week, hoping that someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: Have you tried running pip from powershell directly inside python's main directory?

Answer (score 0):

virtualenvs can break occasionally especially if the somebody updated the python executable the virtualenv was based or some packages / shared libraries of it.

I'd suggest to try out with a new virtualenv. (delete the broken one and replace it)

Further.

for debugging I suggest to type following two commands:
`type -a python` and `type -a pip`

In case your search path has some hidden surprises it could be safer to call
`python -m pip` instead of `python` though in a properly setup virtualenv it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: when i type `type -a python`, it says: python is /usr/bin/python.

Comment: and when i type `type -a pip`, it says: pip is /home/unidaweb/unidaproject/unidaenv/bin/pip
pip is /usr/bin/pip

Comment: how can i delete the old one and replace it with new? do i need some commands to remove it?

Comment: If  `type -a` shows multiple lines then the first line is the one that you're interested in.

This is surprising.
Normally if you get pip from your virtualenv you get python as well from it.

You can try to type `hash -r` and then again l`type -a python`

If this doesn't work type
`export PATH="/home/unidaweb/unidaproject/unidaenv/bin/pip:$PATH"`, then `hash -r` and retry once more

Comment: i tried the commands above and it still doesn't work. when i type `type -a python`, it is still giving me the same result.

Comment: when i type `type -a python3`, i get : `(unidaenv) root@UnidaWebApplication:/home/unidaweb/unidaproject# type -a python3
python3 is /home/unidaweb/unidaproject/unidaenv/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3`.